# Where to find a list of printers which require my cartridge type?

Tags: inkjet-printer, hp-officejet, cartridge

My HP 4355 Officejet printer recently died, and I have lots of unused cartridges.

Is there a list of printers which would require the HP 21 ink cartridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Full Cartridge Compatibility List](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=bpa00585) - You'll find there everything.

Tip: Press Ctrl+F in your browser, fill in the search box the number "21" and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Many sellers of cartridges have lists such as this one from kioskea.net

UNI Remanufactured HP 21 HP21 Ink Cartridge For Printer Deskjet 3900, 3910, 3915, 3920, 3930, 3940,3918,3938.3930v HP Deskjet D1311, D1320, D1330, D1341, D1360, D1368, D1420, D1445,D1460, D1470,D1560 D230